# Apache DirectoryRoot configuration?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, server

I have apache running on Ubuntu, my initial directory structure was like :

```
var/www/html/myproject,
```

Now I had cloned a git repository in html folder above now my directory structure becomes :

1] `var/www/html/myproject` this is intact,

2] `var/www/html/my_repo/myproject` this is newly created after cloning,

Now I want apache to deploy this newly created 2nd dir as root, hence I made the change in file located at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-deafult.conf` with following changes :

```
 DocumentRoot var/www/html/my_repo/myproject
```

Then restarted the apache but somehow, server is still loading pages from `var/www/html/myproject` instead of `var/www/html/my_repo/myproject`.

So is there any extra config changes that I have missed OR Do I need some permissions to be given to cloned repository files ? How do I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your original DocumentRoot in apache configuration file? If you didn't, change it, if you did, just reset browser cache by Ctrl+F5 or open page in Private Mode.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out it was `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` where the seperate cofiguration file only for myproject named myproject.config in which I made following changes :

```
DocumentRoot var/www/html/my_repo/myproject & also
<Directory var/www/html/my_repo/myproject>
      Options  Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
```

Now server is taking new directory as root.